# Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect() in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, ldap

I'm trying to connect to my LDAP server via PHP, but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
roshan

Comment: Im trying to connect to the open ds

Comment: It doesn't matter where you're trying to connect - you haven't installed php ldap extension.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but with Solaris.  I think I _do_ have LDAP enabled with PHP.  See http://pastie.org/1982091 for output of phpinfo() and search for LDAP or "ldap".  You should see '--with-ldap=shared,/opt/csw' among others.  So I don't know what else I'm missing.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Make sure the [**LDAP extension**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php) is installed and enabled. This answer assumes you have PHP5, however, things should work similarly for PHP7 as well.

**Install LDAP Extension**

There should be a package named like **php5-ldap**:

```
aptitude show php5-ldap
Paquet : php5-ldap
...
Description : LDAP module for php5                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 This package provides a module for LDAP functions in PHP scripts.
```

Thus, the package can usually be installed like:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-ldap
```

If you do not use `apt-get`, use the equivalent command for the package manager you use.

**Enable LDAP Extension**

To enable the package after installation, you can use this command:

```
sudo php5enmod ldap
```

If you get any error message from the above command, it means something went wrong.

**Note:** After enabling the package, you usually have to restart / reload services so that the newly enabled module is recognized. For apache, you can do this by:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you do not use apache, please use the equivalent command for your server.

Comment: I think we should restart the server after installation.

Comment: You'll need to restart the apache service after installing this package. `sudo service apache2 restart` should do the trick in Ubuntu.

Comment: make sure after the ldap is installed there is a ldap.so in php lib folder and also a ldap.ini added to php config or ldap extension is enabled, some times installation will not add, either rerun the install or add manually

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-ldap
```

And don't afraid to google.